# Laravel Form Request custom error message for date_format rule

Tags: laravel, validation, message

I want to add a custom message on date_format validation in laravel but conldn't find any thing.How i can add a custom message I have used this

$messages = [
'postmeta.event_type.required' => 'event type is required',
'postmeta.event_type.date_format' => 'This is not working i want to add a custom message here',
];

```
    $rules = [
        'postmeta.start_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'postmeta.end_date' => 'required|date_format:Y-m-d',
        'postmeta.start_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i:s',
        'postmeta.end_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i:s',
    ];
```

But not getting the desire custom message. I am getting "The postmeta.end date does not match the format Y-m-d." but i want just event date.

Comment: Did you check the docs here?
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

In `{project}\resources\lang` path, you can see different types of languages. for change validation message it just enough find the field intended in `validation.php` and change the message.

you should change this:

```php
'date_format' => 'The :attribute does not match the format :format.',
```

UPDATED:

in laravel V9 the lang folder is at the root of the project.